# Why isn't my Cisco VPN receiving network packets?

Tags: 12.10, vpn, cisco, vpnc

I'm experiencing a problem since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10.

I've 3 Cisco VPN profiles (pcf format, the old ones, not the anyconnect type). Every of these profiles worked correctly on Ubuntu12.04, with vpnc packages installed, but with a fresh installation of Ubuntu12.10 and vpn one of that profiles stopped working.

I correctly set up the VPN connection, the secrets are confirmed by the secure gateway, but nothing works. I cannot reach any host on that network.

With both ifconfig and Wireshark I've seen that I don't recieve packets, I've only traffic going out.

Can anyone help me out to troubleshoot and resolve the problem :)?

UPDATE:
The profile that isn't working with Ubuntu12.10 works fine with the official Cisco VPN client under MS Windows.

Comment: Do you have other people successfully using the PCF that is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

in case you could not solve it yet. Directly after updating to 12.10 ,y VPN was not working either. I first had to allow all deactivated software sources again and then make an apt-get update / upgrade. Afterwards everything worked fine again.